# Android: getApplication() is undefined for type View.OnClickListener()

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am currently trying to implement the log in facility for Facebook within my android app. I am encountering a problem with

```
Intent diaryIntent = new Intent(getApplication(), DiaryListActivity.class);
```

With the error **The method getApplication() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener**. I have looked at other questions regarding this problem however I haven't managed to find a solution. Personally I believe it might be something to do to the fact I am using fragments, but I am new to this concept so don't understand how to solve the problem, or if it even is something to do with this.

**Class**

```
public class SelectionFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "SelectionFragment";
private ImageButton mAddButton;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selection, 
            container, false);
    mAddButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.diaryform_home_add);

    mAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //Listens for a user to interact with the save button
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do something to save the data
            Intent diaryIntent = new Intent(getApplication(), DiaryListActivity.class);
            startActivity(diaryIntent);

        }
    });

    return view;
```

Any guidance is appreciated, thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** @mike20132013 @codeMagic @crazyPixel All gave me right answers, but I can't give them all the correct answer so I gave the first answer the correct tick. Thanks for the answers though, appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start the activity you need to use the activity context within the fragment use -

`getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

instead of

```
getApplication()
```

to move on to that activity use -

```
getActivity().startActivity(intent)
```

A good thumb rule to remember is that fragments are "inside" activites i.e. their context (and everything related) comes from the activity they resides in.

Answer (score 2):

Change your:

```
Intent diaryIntent = new Intent(getApplication(), DiaryListActivity.class);
```

to

Change

```
Intent diaryIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DiaryListActivity.class);
```

Since you are using fragments you have to use getActivity() instead of context.getApplicationContext().

I am pretty sure this will work..Good Luck .. :)

Comment: No Problem.. I am glad I was able to help .. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Intent diaryIntent = new Intent(getApplication(), DiaryListActivity.class);
```

to

```
Intent diaryIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DiaryListActivity.class);
```

You need a `Context` for the `Intent` Constructor not an application though I think you meant to have `getApplicationContext()` but, either way, just use the `Context` of the `View` clicked.

[All About Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: @barryspikebob I'm glad it works for you. This can be slightly better than some other ways of doing it for a couple reasons including it is more portable if you want to move this code to a different `onClick()` or similar